# Any way to find a Process Builder that I Deleted?

Tags: process-builder

Is there any way to find a Process Builder Process that I deleted?

Like some 15 hour rule where I can find things I deleted that I shouldn't have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no recycle bin for things like Process Builders, Flows, Workflow Rules, Assignment Rules, Sharing Rules, etc. Once you delete these types of items, they are gone forever. This is one of the reasons why Salesforce recommends using Salesforce DX, to keep a repository of your metadata in case you need to fix these kinds of mistakes. If you happen to have a Sandbox created, you might be able to find a copy of the Process Builder in the Sandbox. Otherwise, you're just going to have to build it again.

Comment: And even if not on DX yet, at least maintaining a source code repository for such scenarios is always recommended.